# Lets encrypt SSL

Tags: ssl, openssl, apache2, ssl-certificate

Im trying install let's encrypt certificate for Ubuntu 16.04 via https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-16-04#step-1-create-the-ssl-certificate

But the result is in the picture ... [image]

Comment: the problem is, that i cant see the proceed link ... for activate it certificate ...

Comment: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/net-err-cert-authority-invalid-error/26805

Comment: In short: you are using a .dev domain. .dev is owned by google and HSTS for this domain is enforced in Chrome. This means that you will not get a dialog which allows you to continue with a self-signed or otherwise untrusted certificate. Also: the link you provide talks about using self-signed certificates and not about using Let's Encrypt as you claimed.